# Unable to conform MKAnnotation protocol in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, mkannotation

When I try to conform `MKAnnotation` protocol it throw error my class does not conform to protocol `MKAnnotation`.  I am using the following code

```
import MapKit
import Foundation

class MyAnnotation: NSObject, MKAnnotation
{

}
```

The same thing is possible with Objective-C.

Comment: Check out this links, the same issue

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24233873/mkannotation-swift

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to implement following required property in the calls:

```
class MyAnnotation: NSObject, MKAnnotation {
    var myCoordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D

    init(myCoordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
        self.myCoordinate = myCoordinate
    }

    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D { 
        return myCoordinate
    }
}
```

Comment: As you mentioned I have implemented coordiante property though I am getting error.  If you have any demo code please share.  Thanks


class MyAnnotation: NSObject, MKAnnotation
{
    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D { get }
    
    
}

Comment: Remove the `var coordinate:...` declaration above the `class...` definition.  That will just cause a compiler error and confuse people.  It's also better practice, at least in examples, to also implement `title` and `subtitle` even though they're "optional" (title will almost always be needed).

Answer (score 2):

In Swift, you have to implement every non-optional variables and methods of a protocol in order to conform to a protocol. Right now, your class is empty, which means it is not conforms now to thw `MKAnnotation` protocol. If you look at the declaraton of `MKAnnotation`:

```
protocol MKAnnotation : NSObjectProtocol {

    // Center latitude and longitude of the annotation view.
    // The implementation of this property must be KVO compliant.
    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D { get }

    // Title and subtitle for use by selection UI.
    optional var title: String! { get }
    optional var subtitle: String! { get }

    // Called as a result of dragging an annotation view.
    @availability(OSX, introduced=10.9)
    optional func setCoordinate(newCoordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D)
}
```

you can see, that if you implement at least the `coordinate` variable, then you conform to the protocol.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simpler version:

```
class CustomAnnotation: NSObject, MKAnnotation {
    init(coordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
        self.coordinate = coordinate
        super.init()
    }
    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
}
```

You don't need to define an extra property `var myCoordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D` as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively (works in Swift 2.2, Xcode 7.3.1) (Note: Swift doesn't provide auto-notifications, so I throw in my own.) --

```
import MapKit

class MyAnnotation: NSObject, MKAnnotation {

// MARK: - Required KVO-compliant Property  
var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D {
    willSet(newCoordinate) {
        let notification = NSNotification(name: "MyAnnotationWillSet", object: nil)
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotification(notification)
    }

    didSet {
        let notification = NSNotification(name: "MyAnnotationDidSet", object: nil)
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotification(notification)
    }
}


// MARK: - Required Initializer
init(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
    self.coordinate = coordinate
}
```

Comment: thanks for the sample code. I'm suspecting my question here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39273459/ios-mkmapview-custom-images-display-on-top-left-corner is related to KVO. but how can mapView observe the coordinate change and redraw the UI?